# Ngrx selector direct or composite

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-selectors

I've got this state

```
export interface State {
  error: string | null;
  loaded: boolean;
  loading: boolean;
  data: MyDto | undefined;
}
```

with this selector

```
export const selectData = createSelector(selectFeature, (state: MyDto) => {
  if (state.data) {
    return state.data;
  }
  return undefined;
});
export const selectError = createSelector(selectFeature, (state: MyDto) => {
  return state.error;
});
export const selectLoaded = createSelector(selectFeature, (state: MyDto) => {
  return state.loading;
});
export const selectLoading = createSelector(selectFeature, (state: MyDto) => {
  return state.loading;
});
```

to void extra rendering I want to have e single selector what's the
best way and why

Direct

```
export const selectVm = createSelector(selectFeature, (state: MyDto) => {
  return state;
});
```

or

```
export const selectVm = createSelector(
  selectError,
  selectLoaded,
  selectLoading,
  selectData
  (error, loaded, loading, data) => {
    return {
      error,
      loaded, 
      loading,
      data
    };
  }
);
```

Comment: I don't think you are going to get any less 'extra rendering' - first one change detection will be initiated whenever any of the values change. Last one will do the same as the new selector will fire every time one of the input selectors does. Second one I don't understand.

Comment: Instead of having error$ | async loading$ | async ... etc you have vm$ | async as vm async trigger reredering